# How to Call servlet from java script through AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

I have a JavaScript function like below

```
function ProviderSearchRequest()
{
    var LegacyUserID    = g_PQContactTree.selectSingleNode( " /LegacyLogin" ).text;
    var LegacyPassword  = g_PQContactTree.selectSingleNode( " /LegacyPassword" ).text;   
}
```

MY SERVLET

```
public class AWDB2BAuthentication extends HttpServlet {
     public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,
          IOException {
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        out.println("User Name: " + req.getRemoteUser());
        String name = (req.getUserPrincipal() == null) ? null : req.getUserPrincipal().getName();
        out.println("Principal Name: " + name);
        out.println("Authentication Type: " + req.getAuthType());
        out.println("Hello World..... ");
      }
```

**How to call the servlet whenver through java function using AJAX?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Super Hornet for your time. If we set $.support.cors = true; Ajax cross browsers issue will get solved

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to define url mapping for your servlet in web.xml in WEB-INF folder and then call your servlet by jquery like this:

```
function getData(){
   var xhr=$.ajax({url:"Servlet Path",type:"GET",
   success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
   }
 });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   getData();
});
```

Comment: I used the code you suggested as below. I didn't avle to call my servlet(  <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>AWDB2BAuthentication</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/AWDB2BAuthentication/*</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping> )
 

var xhr=$.ajax({url:"http://localhost:8080/pqawdTestWebApp/AWDB2BAuthentication?awdUserId= " + awdUserId ,type:"GET",
      success:function(data){
         console.log(data);
      }
    });
   }

   $(document).ready(function(){
      getData();

Comment: Object Expected at getData(); line number dailog box appear when I called through IE8 browser.
Thanks

Comment: What about other browsers?

Comment: the mappings are OK because you don't get Error 404 ( not found). I think you got Error 500( internal server error) not related to my answer. So, you have to check server logs to find out what is wrong.